# how to handle NetworkOnMainThreadException while reading text from a file which is present on server

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

i am geting NetworkOnMainThreadException while i am trying to read the text from a .txt file which is present on server how can i solve this problem
thanks in advance.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        TextView tv= new TextView(this);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);



        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();


        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://linktomywebsite/textfile.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(str +"\n");
                tv.setText(content);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e){
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e){

            tv2.setText("not connecting to server");
            setContentView(tv2);
        }

    };        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Network operations are [forbidden](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) on ui thread since api 11 . You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), requesting string in `doInBackground` and showing results in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0):

cearte a new thread and do heavy operation like getting the data from that......
ans use handler or Async Task to update the result on UI

as in this 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to permit Network operation(Though it is not advisable to do so). Add this below onCreate().

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```